# Shoulder Rod Stretch, Difference Using Wooden Bar Rod or Towel Rope

Tags: exercise, stretching, flexibility, yoga, gymnastics

Whats the difference in doing the shoulder bar dislocation stretch with a regular wooden rod vs a towel/rope? (Note: I know the second picture is using a towel, but I use a rope and pull it wide tight).

https://youtu.be/IWDN-RW-at8?t=239

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't explain the exact mechanics of it, but essentially the difference is with a pole your hands / arms are fixed into a certain rotation (let's call it parallel), whereas with a towel / rope / band your hands and arms can rotate to place the shoulder joint into a more comfortable movement pattern.

I find using something flexible easier as it allows me to externally rotate my shoulders as they pass over my head, allowing me to drop my arms lower behind me.

However, I believe that I get a better effect from a solid object like a broomstick as it forces the shoulders to stretch the particularly tight muscles at the front of my shoulders, rather than allowing shoulder rotation to find an easier way to move.

Comment: okay interesting, thanks